# How to run script for each element in pipe?

Tags: shell, powershell

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer -and `
$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-31)} | Remove-Item -whatif

Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -and `
@(Get-ChildItem -Lit $_.Fullname -r | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer}).Length -eq 0} |
Remove-Item -recurse -whatif
```

the above Script can work properly, now I want to combine it with the fllowing script into one script:

```
$path = "<path to file>"
$shell = new-object -comobject "Shell.Application"
$item = $shell.Namespace(0).ParseName("$path")
$item.InvokeVerb("delete")
```

Here is my combined Script:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -and `
@(Get-ChildItem -Lit $_.Fullname -r | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer}).Length -eq 0} |
$path = $_.Fullname
$shell = new-object -comobject "Shell.Application"
$item = $shell.Namespace(0).ParseName("$path")
$item.InvokeVerb("delete") -recurse -whatif
```

but, I always get the error message:

```
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:3 char:7

You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At line:6 char:28

Unexpected token 'recurse' in expression or statement.
At line:6 char:29

Unexpected token '-whatif' in expression or statement.
At line:6 char:37
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: What is the *full* combined script?

Comment: hi, I have posted the combined script.

Comment: Oh yes, that looks very invalid :( It looks like the goal is "do" the 2nd snippet "for each element" in the pipe, yes? If so, see [ForEach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009154/powershell-foreach-piping-confusion) - in short, `.. | ForEach-Object { "2nd script" }` - but also see `foreach`.

Comment: could you post the final Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet (alias is foreach) in the last part of your pipeline.  Also, you don't want to create the Shell.Application object each time in your pipeline:

```
$shell = new-object -comobject "Shell.Application"
Get-ChildItem -recurse | 
    Where {$_.PSIsContainer -and `
           @(Get-ChildItem -Lit $_.Fullname -r | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer}).Length -eq 0} |
    Foreach {
        $item = $shell.Namespace(0).ParseName(($_.Fullname))
        $item.InvokeVerb("delete")
    }
```

That said, I'm not sure why you just don't use the `Remove-Item` cmdlet e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem . -r | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -and !$(Get-ChildItem $_.fullname)} | 
    Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

To make this a script, just put the above command in a .ps1 file like so:

```
-- Contents of DeleteEmptyDirs.ps1 --
param([string]$path, [switch]$whatif)

Get-ChildItem $path -r | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -and !$(Get-ChildItem $_.fullname)} | 
    Remove-Item -WhatIf:$whatif
```

Then invoke like so:

```
PS> .\DeleteEmptyDirs c:\temp -WhatIf 
PS> .\DeleteEmptyDirs c:\temp
```

Comment: Your Script can work properly, but I always get the Prompt MesssageBox, how can i avoid it?

Comment: Which prompt message box do you get?  Try using the `-Force` parameter on the Remove-Item cmdlet.

Comment: I'm using  $item.InvokeVerb("delete"), and the MessageBox is"Are you sure you want to move this folder to the Recyle Bin?"

Comment: Why don't you use `Remove-Item` and then you won't be prompted?

Comment: Because I don't want delete them permanently, I probably make mistakes when doing such thing. Later, I can check the Recyle Bin to avoid mistakes.

Comment: Then find your Recycle Bin, right click it and select Properties and see if "Display delete confirmation dialog" is checked, if so, uncheck it and try again.  BTW, the point of using the `-WhatIf` parameter on Remove-Item is that it will show you what it is going to delete without actually deleting it.  You have to remove the `-WhatIf` parameter to get it to delete the dirs.

Comment: Oops, this method can actually work as expected, but, I want to control it in the Script. Is it possible?